# In the Excel plugin for Rally, what is the xParent field?

Tags: excel, rally

I installed the Rally plugin for Excel and did a query for User Stories.  There is a Parent field which gives me just the Name field from the parent story.  I tried xParent field, but it gives me an JSON string that looks like an object with an ObjectID, but it doesn't match the parent story (and not every story that has a parent also has a value in xParent).

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? I've tried to query and/or find xParent on User Stories via the latest (1.11) add-in and can't seem to reproduce the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I feel silly.  The field xParent is a custom field.  It has nothing to do with Parent.

The cool thing is that I learned you can type Parent.FormattedID to have a column show the Parent's FormattedID.